# Cors Error When I do a redirect from the server

Tags: reactjs, go, cors

I have a server running on localhost:8090, which I make a request to from a React App running on localhost:3000 . The aim of this request is to perform some operations and when it is done, it does a redirect to https://www.google.com/ from the backend. This is what it looks like.

Frontend:

```
function processReq() {
  fetch(`http://localhost:8090/some-process`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
      }
    }
  )
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Backend

```
r.GET("/some-process", handlers.DoProcess)

func DoProcess(c *gin.Context) {

    // processes request
    var w http.ResponseWriter = c.Writer

    http.Redirect(w, c.Request, "https://www.google.com", http.StatusSeeOther)
}
```

All of these works well, but I get a Cors error that looks like this

```
Access to fetch at 'https://www.google.com/' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8090/some-process') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Mind you, I have setup cors on my backend and it looks something like this

````
func CORS() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, Accept, Origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, Accept, Origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
            c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
            c.AbortWithStatus(204)
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}```
````

Comment: You can't fetch google from the client. Do you want to redirect the browser instead?

Comment: Yes. I want to redirect to google after processing. Instead of sending a Json response

Comment: You cannot do that. When the response to the initial request is a redirect to another different origin (`https://www.google.com`, in this case), the CORS check starts from scratch for the origin in question. Obviously, `https://www.google.com` isn't configured for CORS, at least not from your client's origin.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is similar to the one described in the answer to [Mongoose redirect not waiting for findByIDAndDelete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74365535/mongoose-redirect-not-waiting-for-findbyidanddelete).

Instead of letting the server respond with a redirect, let it respond with 200 OK and have the client execute

```js
location.href = "https://www.google.com";
```

when it receives this response.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing cors errors is because google is not returning permissible access control headers.

The more fundamental issue is you're trying to redirect the browser as part of a `fetch` request which won't work; if google did allow cross origin access, you would just be returning the HTML response in your fetch call which isn't that useful.

Instead, you should just return a 200 in your server response and have the client redirect the browser window to google.

```js
function processReq() {
  fetch(`http://localhost:8090/some-process`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
      }
    }
  )
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      window.location.href = 'https://google.com';
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```